# Rails - Devise: how to set _id as username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

Usernames are unique so I want to use them instead of long MongoDB _ids. How can I do that with devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the id as the username you will need to adjust the generated migration file to have it as username and not email.

You should also change the the file found at `config/initializers/devise.rb` 
from `config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]` to `config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`

Generate the views by running `rails generate devise:views` and modify the appropriate view files to use the new username field.